# Find the limit of $\sin^2(1/x^2)$ when $x\to 0$ or show the limit doesn't exist

Tags: limits

Find the limit or show the limit doesn't exist for

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin^2 \frac{1}{x^2}$$

I'm relatively new to limits and i'm unsure of how to show this.

I thought of breaking it down further to

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin^2 \frac{1}{x^2}=\bigl(\lim_{x\to 0} \sin \frac{1}{x^2} \bigr)^2$$ but I'm stuck here.

Comment: **Hint:** Does the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n$ exist? (Recall that $\sin$ keeps oscillating between $-1$ and $1$)

Comment: $n=x$? $0=\infty$?

Comment: Do you mean x instead of n

Comment: @Workaholic More than that is necessary to conclude (otherwise, $\sin(\pi n)$ would diverge as well).

Comment: Yeah sorry it's $x$. have been working on so many problems my brain ain't thinking straight. thanks!

Comment: @Did Of course. I was giving him a start.

Comment: @Workaholic But now $x\to0$, with presumably $x$ any real, hence your argument "re-works"...

Comment: @Workaholic I thought of maybe a  substitution actually to make it become $\lim_{1/x \to \infty} sin^2 x^2$ and then making use of the oscillating property will that work too?

Comment: Title and body contain different questions.

Comment: @Danxe Yes, you could also use the identity $$\sin^2 x=\dfrac{1-\cos 2x}2,$$ and the fact that $\cos$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$x=\dfrac2{\sqrt{\pi*k}}$ then $\sin^2(\dfrac1{x^2})=\sin^2(\dfrac{\pi*k}4)=0,\dfrac12,1,\dfrac12,0,\dfrac12$,...